# Example of holomorphic function from unit disc to itself

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

let $f:\mathbb{D} \to \mathbb{D}$ be analytic function with $f(0)=0$,where $\mathbb{D}$ is the open disc $\{z \in \mathbb{C}:|z|<1 \}$ then

$1.|f'(0)|=1$

$2.|f(\frac{1}{2})|\leq \frac{1}{2}$

$3.|f(\frac{1}{2})| \leq \frac{1}{4}$

$4.|f'(0)| \leq \frac{1}{2}$

Can I use here Cauchy integral formula? please give me some hint i have no idea about it.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know Schwarz' lemma?

Comment: I had read it many time but i'm confused in the statement.I can't understand second part of it.

Comment: Can you think of some function $f$ as in the statement? Constant function... Identity function... do the properties 1-2-3-4 hold for them?

Comment: @cheapeffectivedietpills if I take identity function then $1,2$ holds.

Comment: Right, so 3 and 4 are disproved by this counterexample. If you take $f$ identically equal to $0$, one of two other statements will be disproved. The remaining one is true by the Schwarz lemma.

Comment: @cheapeffectivedietpills In the statement of Schwarz's lemma If $|f(z)|<1$ and $f(0)=0$ then $|f(z)|=1$ or $|f(z)| = |z| $ where $z \neq 0$  but i'm confuse in this statement because for identity function we get $|f(z)| \leq |z|$ but also we have $|f'(0)|=1$

Comment: You already considered $f(z)\equiv z$. What I also suggested was $f(z)\equiv 0$. This is a counterexample to another of the statements.

Comment: @cheapeffectivedietpills ok I understand.How can i prove $2.$?

Comment: By the Schwarz lemma.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is 2. There is a result that if let f:D→D be analytic function with f(0)=0,where D is the open disc {z∈C:|z|<1} then |f(z)|<=|z|. this is where it comes from.